# Trying to make a log function

Tags: python

I want to make a log function in my script but I don`t know why it gives me this error

```
File "c:/Users/x/x/x", line 33
    log = open(f"Log/{realDate.strftime("%x")}.txt", "a")
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here`s the code that is causing the problem

```
realDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    log = open(f"Log/{realDate.strftime("%x")}.txt", "a")
    log.write("Hello Stackoverflow!")
    log.close()
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: You aren't using Python 3.6 or later, and thus don't have f-string support.

Comment: Or you are using double quotes inside double quotes without escaping them (?)

Comment: Yes, it's the double quotation marks.  `%x` is *not* part of a string; it's between two strings.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The syntax error in that case would point to the `%` following the `"` that actually closes the f-string (as opposed to defining the argument to `strftime`).

Comment: In other words, the lexer is still greedy; `{` doesn't make it reset its notion of whether you are recognizing a string literal or not.

Comment: Hm, interesting. A `%` (or something) is apparently enough to change how the error is reported; compare the error messages for `f"{print("%x")}"` and `f"{print("x")}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to nest double quotes inside double quotes; f-strings don't allow that. You would need to change one or the other to another style of quotes. For example:

```
log = open(f'Log/{realDate.strftime("%x")}.txt', "a")
```

---

<strike>The main problem is that you aren't using a version of Python that supports f-strings. Make sure you are using Python 3.6 or later.</strike> (Update: Even in Python 3.6 or later, the identified location of the error can shift:

```
>>> f"{print("%x")}"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f"{print("%x")}"
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> f"{print("x")}"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f"{print("x")}"
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

)

Comment: Thanks that helped. I didn't know I couldn't do that even inside the f-string brackets.